# Openpyxl setting a number format in a cell

Tags: python, excel, openpyxl

I'm trying to set a number format in a specific cell and I'm not getting any errors.

```
ws["C13"].value = valuec13 # value is 04:15:34
ws["C13"].number_format = 'h:mm AM/PM'
```

However, when I open the generated excel file the cell is not formatted.

[image: In the excel the format is:]

BUT, if I press in the formula text box the format of the cell is updated.

[image]

Does anyone know why this happens?

Comment: What is the precise value that you assigned to C1?

Comment: Edited, I just use the valuec13 variable to receive the value, in this case "04:15:34"

Comment: That's a string and the number format will have no effect.

Comment: Thank you @CharlieClark , make sense, I will need to check how to pass the hour as int?

Comment: You should be able to pass it as a datetime.time